# Vue.JS animate width on elements in loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have tried vue transitions and classic jQuery each loop but nothing works. If I am creating a list of items like so:

```
<ul id="goal-list" class="item-list" >

 <li v-for="item in list" class="goal" transition="bounce">
        <img :src=" 'https://s3.com/' + item.badge_image ">
        <h3 >{{ item.badge_social }}</h3>
        <div class="line">
            <div class="line-percent" transition="progress" :style="{ 'width' : (item.badge_progress /  item.badge_goal) * 100 + '%'}"></div>
        </div>

    </li>

    <infinite-loading :on-infinite="onInfinite" :distance="distance"  spinner="waveDots" >
                <span slot="no-more">
                    Sorry, we reached the end. 
                </span>
    </infinite-loading>

        </ul>
```

How can I animate the width of `line-percent`? Basically these are goals I want to animate the user progress from 0 width to their current percent (which is spit out as width currently). Before I moved to Vue.js it was easy:

set a data attribute to store the width of each element I want to animate then something like:

```
$('.goal').each(function( index ) {

  var percent = $(this).find('.line').attr('data-percent');

  $(this).find('.line-percent').animate({
    width:'100%'
  },3000);
});
```